# No sound when using Bluetooth on Cordova Android with Web Audio API

Tags: android, cordova, audio, webview, bluetooth

I'm using the Web Audio API to play sound files in my Cordova Crosswalk app. Everything works fine until trying to use a Bluetooth headset and the issue only occurs on Android. Bluetooth sound works fine if I use the Cordova Media Plugin though I need the Web Audio API for the biquad filter and panner.

The only way to get the sound to work with Bluetooth is to start playing the sound and then connect the Bluetooth device after. If the Bluetooth is connected before starting the app is when the problem happens. I have also tried adding Bluetooth permission to the AndroidManifest.

Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: No. The issue has been reported to Chromium over a year ago and they don't seem to have much interest in resolving it. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=635686&q=bluetooth%20web%20audio&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: Same problem here with an exception: After having connected my headset to the bluetooth, the sounds played with AudioContext API in my App get lot of cut, every sounds is jerky (like when a video is laggy). Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Please add your info to the bug report so that they can finally get this fixed. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=748157

Comment: I didn't find a 'clean' solution yet, but I found a hint about an attribute called baseLatency... You can read more details about it here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649095/cordova-no-sound-on-bluetooth-speakers/47328748#47328748)