# cordova no sound on bluetooth speakers

Tags: android, ios, cordova, bluetooth

I am working on an android   (and IOS) application, the application plays audio messages without problem. My problem is as follow:
if the mobile is already connected to bluetooth (bluetooth enabled and connected), if then I launch my application and I play an audio file in this case I hear nothing neither on the telephine nor on the bluetooth speaker.

But, if I launch my application and then I activate the bluetooth,then play the audio file, there is no problem, the sound goes out well on my bluetooth speakers.

The solution I used for now is that when I launch my application I disable completely the bluetooth and then I restart it on the onDeviceready (using a plugin cordova) it works fin like that  but it is not ideal as solution, it is very annoying for the users that the bluetooth disconnect and reconnect especially when it is the bluetooth of the car.

Does anyone have the same problem and can you help me find another solution.

I use the latest versions of Cordova (7.0.1), android (6.2.3) ...
and I use the plugova cordova-plugin-bluetoothle to restart bluetooth (disable then enable after the launch of the application)

Any Idea please?

Comment: any idea will be appreciated......

Answer (score 1):

Exact same problem here! I'm working on a musical webapp for Android (6.4.0) and iOS (4.5.3) built with Cordova (7.1.0). I use the webaudio API to play sounds. Everything works great on every platforms except in this specific case:

If the bluetooth is enabled and connected before I launch my App there is no sounds at all playing. This problem occurs **only on Android**. On some model/type of Android devices it works, on some others it doesn't... Example:

- Samsung J3 (Android v5.1.1) = no sounds playing
- LENOVO TB2 (Android v5.1.1) = no sounds playing
- HUAWEI VTR (Android v7.0) = no sounds playing
- LG G6 (Android v7.0) = it works like a charm!

Unfortunately I didn't find any 'clean' solutions yet. I do the same than yours (BT=bluetooth):

1. force to disable BT if this one is connected,
2. reload the entire page,
3. re-connect the BT.

The only hint I found during my tests is about an attribute into the AudioContext object. The AudioContext object has a attribute called **baseLatency**. The [official DOC](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#attributes-0) isn't really clear about it:

> This represents the number of seconds of processing latency incurred by the AudioContext passing the audio from the AudioDestinationNode to the audio subsystem [...]

What I understood is that this property give you an estimation (in seconds) of the time/delay needed by AudioContext to bring a sound to his destination...

Right after the AudioContext has been initialized in your code, you can ask for this **baseLatency** (read-only property):

```
var context = new AudioContext();
console.log(context.baseLatency);// 0.008 for example
```

What I noticed during my tests, is that this baseLatency is **always** higher than 0.2 everytime the problem occurs.

Example with bluetooth **DISabled**:

```
// baseLatency on computer = 0.008
// baseLatency on iOS devices = 0.05
// baseLatency on Android devices = 0.05
```

Example with bluetooth **ENabled**:

```
// baseLatency on computer = 0.008 (same)
// baseLatency on iOS devices = 0.05 (same)
// baseLatency on (some) Android devices = 0.2 (HIGHER)
```

Well, I did this test hundreds times, each times the same result. If BT is enabled before you launch the App on **some** Androids devices, the **baseLatency** will be higher than 0.2 meaning the AudioContext won't be able to play any sounds in your app. This is not a solution I know, but that can helps a little by letting you know for sure if the App will play sounds or not.

I tried to re-initialize the AudioContext object, but this doesn't works at all... the baseLatency stay the same even if you reconstruct the AudioContext object.

I hope this tiny hint could help us to find a solution!

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. The only trick I found to work around the problem was to detect if the device is already paired in Bluetooth when the application starts. If it is, I force the Bluetooth to deactivate, force the page to be refreshed, and then tell the user that he can reconnect its bluetooth device... Not a very clean solution... If you find any solutions/ideas please share it on this page!

Comment: Looks like related bug for Chrome Android: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=635686